# Почему не срабатывает такой код?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка:

```
const id = this.data.test.id
```

Но бывает так что `this.data` может содержать немного другую структуру, и тогда чтобы получить **id** нужно делать так:

```
const id = this.data.testID
```

В коде я сделал так:

```
const id = this.data.test.id || this.data.testID;
```

Но в итоге приложение падает с ошибкой

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Делай через тернарник

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можете привести пример?

Comment: Ты не знаешь что такое тернарник?

Comment: @iKey  `this.data?.test?.id || this.data?.testID;`

Answer (score 1):

```
const id = this.data.test.id || this.data.testID;
```

Решение "в лоб" - поменять местами:

```
const id = this.data.testID || this.data.test.id;
```

Иное решение - использовать тернарный условный оператор:

```
const id = this.data.test ? this.data.test.id : this.data.testID;
```

Третий вариант - optional chaining вместе с nullish coalescing:

```
const id = this.data.test?.id ?? this.data.testID;
```

Почему выдает ошибку? Потому что объект `this.data.test` равен `undefined`. А вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству `id` этого объекта.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
const id = this.data?.test?.id || this.data?.testID;
```

Comment: И почему же это решение хорошее?

Comment: @ΝNL993 оно работает, что еще нужно?

Comment: К примеру нормальные проверки, у вас проверка на каждом углу (Вот: `data?`, `test?`, `.. || ..` и снова `data?`), А судя по тексту в вопросе там может быть всего два разных случая `this.data.test.id` и `this.data.testID`, то есть достаточно проверять есть ли `testID`, если нет тогда возвращаем корректное значение. `const id = this.data.testID ? this.data.testID : this.data.test.id`